# WooCommerce custom header background image

Tags: image, woocommerce, background, header

I use woocommerce.php in WordPress, it contains the woocommerce_content(); line to display WooCommerce informations (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/). I like to add a custom header background image to this page. Basically I generate a Meta Box, which has an input field to upload the image. I retrieve the informations like:

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), header_background_image', true );
```

and display it like so:

```
$headerBackground = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'header_background_image', true );
<header class="header" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $headerBackground; ?>')">
```

This code works well all pages but WooCommerce and I can't figure out why. Do you have any idea?

Comment: *"This code works well all pages but WooCommerce…"*… do you mean that it works on all pages except on WooCommerce? Maybe for example because WooCommerce single products are a custom post type (so not really pages) and you will need to enable that metabox on "product" post type too.

Comment: I thought you are right LoicTheAztex, and I enabled it like so:
"post-type":["post","page","product"], but nothing happens, still not displays the page the background image.

Comment: Do you correctly display the url of the image in the `style` attribute of the `<header>` element?

Comment: Good question, but I think it' s correct:
<header class="header" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'set_header_background', true ); ?>');">